# List of tables empty if put after list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm a not an expert of LateX, so I apologize if my question is too obvious. 
Here is my problem: I'm writing my master thesis by Overleaf (class book), and I noticed that my  List of tables shows nothing, it is completely empty, when the code is:

```
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
```

But if I invert the order between Lot and Lof, such as

```
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
```

Then the normal list of tables appears, as it should be. I tried to clear cached files, compile two times, but I'm missing something probably obvious. Any idea? I can provide a MWE (even if it would not be that minimal)

Here is a MWE with all the packages I use. Where there is \chapter(Abstract) (and similar) I actually use \input{Abstract.tex} in my thesis. I didn't paste the bibliography part (and the image is casual, just an example).
Many thanks to anyone has a clue about what I'm missing!

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside, openright, cleardoublepage=empty
]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\geometry{a4paper,top=35mm,bottom=35mm,inner=30mm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase\rightmark} 
\fancyhead[LE]{\textit\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[font=small,format=hang,labelfont={sf,bf}]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}%for Appendix

\usepackage{floatrow}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit \year {y}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{guit}
\newlength{\adjust}
\usepackage{verbatim}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5
\usepackage{url} % To break long url
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5
\usepackage{nomencl}[noprefix] %% Symbols List
\makenomenclature

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{G}{\large{Greek letters}}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{R}{\large{Roman letters}}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{O}{Other Symbols}{}}}%
]}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newenvironment{abstract}%
{\cleardoublepage\null\vfill\begin{center}%
\bfseries\abstractname\end{center}}%
{\vfill \null }


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  DOCUMENT

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

% \frontmatter
% \includepdf[]{FrontespizioTESI}   % this document layout is compulsory fro my University
% \thispagestyle{empty}
% \cleardoublepage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{flushright}
\null\vspace {\stretch {1}}
\textit{Eventual text here}
\vspace {\stretch{2}}\null
\end{flushright}


    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables

%   \renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
%   \newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
%   \renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}}
%     \printnomenclature



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\mainmatter
\chapter*{Abstract}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
% \thispagestyle{empty}
This work aims to ...


\chapter*{Introduction}
\pagestyle{plain}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
This is going to be the introduction of this work...

\chapter{First chapter}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
This will be the first chapter...
This could be a figure
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{Cervino.jpg}
    \caption[image of Cervino]{This is Cervino mountain}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

and this one a table:

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|l|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Hs {[}m{]}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Tp {[}s{]}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Direction {[}°{]}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{DSPR {[}°{]}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Resolution}}                   \\ \cline{5-6} 
                                     &                                      &                                             &                                        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{fine grid} & coarse grid               \\ \hline
0.5                                  & 15.2                                 & -65                                         & 15                                     & 300                            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3000} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption[wave data table]{This is table on wave data}
\label{Table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Did you compile the document at least twice in both cases?

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to have a MWE with one table, one figure, and your two `listof`.  That might end up being 20 lines of code.

Comment: Yes, I compiled both twice, just the first case does not work. Regarding the MWE, funny thing is that it works, as it should and as it always did in my previous works, in both ways. I write down the MWE, with all the packages that I use in my thesis, maybe there's some conflict. I apologize for the length, but I think it's better be honest. Where I write \chapter*{Abstract}, there is actually a \input{Abstract.tex} in my thesis file, and so for all the others \chapter* or \chapter

Comment: Off-topic: (i) some packages you load twice, (ii) the `hyperref` should be loaded last., if you load `hyperef` you not need to load `url`, ...

Comment: Thank you for the off-topic @Zarko, I correct these things. Any tips for the problem btw?

Comment: @Kelto7, I test your document example (with shortened preamble) and it works with any order of ToC, LoF and LoT.

Comment: Thanks @Zarko, as I wrote I know that this MWE works. On the contrary, my master thesis work doesn't, although I copied and pasted the same preamble. The only differences with this MWE are the bilbiography commands (could they affect the Lot?) and the chapters added as \input{chapters.tex}. Is there a way I could solve this problem? Any suggestions might be useful, I must submit the work in days.

Comment: The only way is compose your thesis from scratch. As starting point use MWE from my answer and than add first all skipped packages (each only one time), than add your definitions. If after that MWE still works, copy your chapter from thesis to this new document (section by section).  In this way you may found where you have source of your problem (if it exist). However, first delete `aux` file of your thesis and compile it again (twice). Unfortunately, I haven't crystal ball to see your document ...

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Zarko, although I would rather not to compile from scratch. Anyway yeah, it might solve the problem. Otherwise, I put List of Tables before the List of Figures, and it compiles correctly... this is the crazy thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reduce your document example to:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside, openright, cleardoublepage=empty]{book}
\usepackage[font=small,format=hang,labelfont={sf,bf}]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents\listoftables\listoffigures
\mainmatter
\chapter{one}
\section{one}
\section{two}
\section{three}
One image
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a}
    \caption[Image of Cervino]{This is Cervino mountain}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
and one a table:
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2   \\ 
\hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption[wave data table]{This is table on wave data}
\label{Table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

and it gives after two compilation desired result. You can extend above MWE with adding packages and definition to its preamble and see, if its result be changed (I expect that will not).

Comment: I finally solved the issue (stupid, my fault): after all the \input{chapter.tex} (1,2,3,etc). I had an appendix.tex, in which there was

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue (stupid, my fault): after all the \input{chapter.tex} (1,2,3,etc). I had an appendix.tex, in which inside the appendix.tex there was, at the beginning:

```
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
```

I changed 0 with 2 and the List of Tables is not empty anymore. It was then a problem of how deeply to show the contents, I guess. Thanks Community!